# How to use different yarn registry regardless of registry in the yarn.lock file?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

My `yarn.lock` file looks like:

```
package@x.x.x:
  version: "x.x.x"
  resolved: "http://registry.yarnpkg.com/package/-/xxxx"
```

But the CI is in intranet and the registry is http://99.12.xx.xx/xxx

How to use intranet registry in CI build regardless of the internet registry in the `yarn.lock` file?

Comment: Does `yarn install --no-lockfile` woks?

Answer (score 17):

This is an old issue on yarn's github repository as you can see [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2566)

I solved this issue by running a sed command to substitute the registry link before installing packages:

```
sed -i -e "s#https://registry.yarnpkg.com/#{YOUR_CI_REGISTRY}#g" yarn.lock
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

To save actual dependencies you can remove a `resolved` directive from the `yarn.lock` file, set your repository and renew `yarn.lock` by `yarn install`

```
sed -i -e "/resolved:* .*$/d" yarn.lock
yarn config set registry <YOUR_REGISTRY>
yarn install
```

To prevent `yarn.lock` break by other developer you can also file a your registry setting into `.yarnrc`

**.yarnrc**

```
registry "<YOUR_REGISTRY>"
```

Comment: `sed -i -e "/resolved:* .*$/d" yarn.lock` is the key.

Also we can use the `NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY` environment variable rather than `yarn config set registry` if we wish. But it won't be applied if yarn.lock is not purged from the resolved directives.